# Video shuts off

Tags: video, hdmi

My first pi, and i have it booting a debian distro fine. But the aggregation is video (hdmi) cuts out unexpectedly at different uptimes. Powering off and on video does not return. Waiting a while to power on video return.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Does only X die or do you see nothing at all? Can you boot without X and see if this works? Is the Pi maybe getting to hot?

Comment: See nothing at all. Unplugged and plugged back in and still can't see anything. Wait a while and plugged back in and can see again. I will check the temperature.

Comment: if the temp is ok then check the voltage. http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!